# Leaflet Humanitarian Layer

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

In Leaflet how to use Humanitarian Layer instead of Standard Layer of OpenStreetMap? The default layer is Standard. There is a slight difference between these layers.

Answer (score 4):

Easy to add as a base layer like this:

```
var mymap = L.map('map').setView([<your Lat>, <your Lng>], 13);
L.TileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
{
attribution:"© OpenStreetMap Contributors. Tiles courtesy of Humanitarian 
OpenStreetMap Team",
maxZoom: 20   
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: is there a us version of this map? maybe at osm.org?

Answer (score 1):

Use this URL:

```
var url = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

The important point is that, in the part where you define **TileLayer**, the **link** and the **attribution** must be related.

```
  const tiles = new L.TileLayer(
    "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
        {
        attribution:"© OpenStreetMap Contributors. Tiles courtesy of 
        Humanitarian OpenStreetMap Team",
        maxZoom:10
        });
        tiles.addTo(this.map);
```

*this.map* is my map element.